# JavaScript not working .addClass

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and the admin template ADMINLTE, and this doesn't work

```
<div class="row" id="efectivo">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Efectivo:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></div>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amountPaid" placeholder="Con cuanto paga" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Vuelto:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></div>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control amountDue" id="amountDue" placeholder="Vuelto" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

 <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="dist/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function () {


    $("#efectivo").addClass('hidden');

        });

</script>
```

My CSS class is working properly but i dont know why the .addClass doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: If I run your code in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fovc6ym/), it does seem to add the class. Can you recreate the issue in a code snippet?

Comment: It definitely does work: http://jsfiddle.net/L4f4hbsf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#efectivo").addClass('hidden');

});
```

Your code doesn't work, because you are creating anonymous function that not have assigned to any event.